# Model the constraints of an integer linear program

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, operations-research

I have to model the costraints of an integer linear program. The objective function is not important here.
Suppose we have $C$ configurations (indexed by $i = 1, \dots, C$) and $T$ time intervals (indexed by $j = 1, \dots, T$). I wish that:

a) only one configuration is active at each time interval;

b) when a configuration has been chosen I must keep it for at least $\bar{t}$ time intervals (with $\bar{t} \leq T$).

So I define the decision variables:

$y(i,j) :=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if configuration $i$ is active at time $j$}; \\[2ex]
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$

For request a) I write the constraints:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^C y(i,j) = 1 \ \ \ \forall \ j = 1, \dots, T.
\end{equation}

Now, I don't know how to proceed with the request b). Any help or suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For part b), you can introduce another binary variable $x_{i,j}$ to indicate the start, together with constraints:
\begin{align}
x_{i,j} &\le y_{i,k} &&\text{for $k\in\{j,\dots,j+\overline{t}-1\}$} \tag1\\
x_{i,j} &\le 1 - y_{i,j-1} \tag2\\
(1 - y_{i,j-1}) + y_{i,j} - 1 &\le x_{i,j} \tag3
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ enforces $x_{i,j} = 1 \implies \land_{k=j}^{j+\overline{t}-1} (y_{i,k} = 1)$.
Constraint $(2)$ enforces $x_{i,j} = 1 \implies y_{i,j-1} = 0$.
Constraint $(3)$ enforces $(y_{i,j-1} = 0 \land y_{i,j} = 1) \implies x_{i,j} = 1$.

---

Alternatively, you can omit $x$ and just impose
$$(1 - y_{i,j-1}) + y_{i,j} - 1 \le y_{i,k} \quad\text{for $k\in\{j+1,\dots,j+\overline{t}-1\}$},$$
equivalently,
$$y_{i,j} - y_{i,j-1} \le y_{i,k} \quad\text{for $k\in\{j+1,\dots,j+\overline{t}-1\}$}, \tag4$$
(where $y_{i,j}$ is treated as $0$ if $j<0$ or $j>T$),
which enforces
$$(y_{i,j-1} = 0 \land y_{i,j} = 1) \implies \bigwedge_{k=j+1}^{j+\overline{t}-1} (y_{i,k} = 1).$$

---

Yet a third approach is to enforce
$$\left(y_{i,j-1} \land \lnot \bigwedge_{k=1}^{\overline{t}} y_{i,j-k}\right) \implies y_{i,j},$$
equivalently,
$$\left(\lnot y_{i,j-1} \lor \bigwedge_{k=1}^{\overline{t}} y_{i,j-k}\right) \lor y_{i,j},$$
which has conjunctive normal form
$$\bigwedge_{k=1}^{\overline{t}} \left(\lnot y_{i,j-1} \lor y_{i,j-k} \lor y_{i,j}\right),$$
yielding linear constraints
$$1 - y_{i,j-1} + y_{i,j-k} + y_{i,j} \ge 1 \quad \text{for $k \in \{1,\dots,\overline{t}\}$}.$$
Rearranging this, we obtain
$$y_{i,j} \ge y_{i,j-1} - y_{i,j-k} \quad \text{for $k \in \{1,\dots,\overline{t}\}$}. \tag5$$
Now we can recover @toronto hrb's formulation by aggregation:
$$y_{i,j} \ge y_{i,j-1} - \frac{1}{\overline{t}}\sum_{k=1}^{\overline{t}} y_{i,j-k} \tag6$$
So $(6)$ is correct but weaker than $(5)$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\land_{k=j}^{j+\overline{t}-1} (y_{i,k} = 1)$?

Comment: $\land$ is logical AND, so it means $y_{i,k}=1$ for each $k$

Comment: Your formulation has a hole. Let's say $\bar{t}=3$. Your formulation might end up with $y_{i,T-2}=0$, but $y_{i,T-1}=y_{i,T}=1$.

Comment: Sorry that I wasn’t explicit about all the indices. Just treat all variables that are out of bounds as $0$. With that convention, one of my constraints is $y_{i,T-1}\le 0$.

Comment: But it doesn't seem that  this prevents $y_{i,T-2}=0, y_{i, T-1}=y_{i,T}=1$. when $\bar{t}=3$. You need to add a set of constraints to force that if $y_{i,T-\bar{t}+1}=0$, then all the rest have to be zero as well.

Comment: When $\overline{t}=3$, one of my constraints (take $j=T-1$ and $k=j+\overline{t}-1$) is $y_{i,T-1}-y_{i,T-2} \le y_{i,T+1}$, and $T+1$ is out of range, so this becomes $y_{i,T-1} - y_{i,T-2} \le 0$, which prohibits $(y_{i,T-2},y_{i,T-1})=(0,1)$.

Comment: Correct. (5) is tighter than (6). BTW, using sentential logic by you to analyze IP constraints is elegant. Would you mind telling me where I can find this technique, either paper or book? It does not seem this appears in any IP book.

Comment: @torontohrb, [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22conjunctive%20normal%20form%22) are several examples on Operations Research StackExchange.  A good reference is Raman, R. and I.E. Grossmann, *Relation Between MILP Modelling and Logical Inference for Chemical Process Synthesis*, **Computers Chem. Engng.** 15 (1991).

Comment: Cool. Thank you for the information.

Comment: @RobPratt I have another curiosity: I would like to modify the problem to accept the cases described by the following example. Suppose that $C=\{1,2\}$, $T=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, $\bar{t}=3$.

I would like to accept solutions like: $y_{1,1}=y_{1,2}=y_{1,3}=y_{1,4}=1, y_{2,5}=y_{2,6}=1$

Configuration $2$ remains active only for 2 time intervals but it is fine because they are final times. How should I change the constraints? My attempt:

Your costraints $(4)$ for $j\in\{1,\dots,T-\bar{t}+1\}$ and $y_{i,j}-y_{i,j-1}\le y_{i,k}$ for $j\in\{T-\bar{t}+2,\dots,T\},k\in\{j,\dots,T\}$. Can it work?

Comment: @LJG The simplest modification is to replace $j+\overline{t}-1$ with $\min(j+\overline{t}-1,T)$ in $(4)$.

Answer (score -1):

Writing variables as $y(i,j)$ is not conventional. Following what you've written, define
$y_{ij}=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if configuration $i$ is active at time $j$}; \\[2ex]
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$

You also need to define binary variables to indicate if a configuration is chosen or not as
$z_i =
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if configuration $i$ is chosen}; \\[2ex]
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$

Now the constraint of part b) can be written as
$$\sum_{j=1}^{T}y_{ij}\ge \bar{t} \cdot z_i, i=1,\cdots, C$$

If configuration $i$ is chosen, $z_i=1$, at least $\bar t$ time intervals are forced; otherwise, $z_i=0$, which places no constraints on time invervals.

Edit for consecutive time intervals. No need to use $z_i$ any more.

Let's use Configuration 1 with $\bar{t}=3$ as an example. The constraints should be like
$$y_{12}\ge y_{11}-\frac{1}{3}y_{11}$$
$$y_{13}\ge y_{12}-\frac{1}{3}(y_{11}+y_{12})$$
$$y_{14}\ge y_{13}-\frac{1}{3}(y_{11}+y_{12}+y_{13})$$
$$y_{15}\ge y_{14}-\frac{1}{3}(y_{12}+y_{13}+y_{14})$$
$$\cdots$$
$$y_{1,T}\ge y_{1,T-1}-\frac{1}{3}(y_{1,T-3}+y_{1,T-2}+y_{1,T-1})$$

Does this work? If $y_{11}=1$, then the first three constraints force $y_{12}=y_{13}=1$, but $y_{14}$ is flexible.

Putting it in a compact form, it becomes
$$y_{ij}\ge y_{i,j-1}-\frac{1}{\bar{t}}\sum_{k=1}^{\bar{t}}y_{i,j-k}, j=2, \cdots, T; i=1,\cdots, C.$$
$$y_{i,0}=y_{i,-1}=0, i=1, \cdots, C.$$

Comment: I think the OP's intent is to force active in *consecutive* time intervals.

Comment: Let's wait for the confirmation from @LJG.

Comment: Yes, I mean consecutive time intervals. For example, if $\bar{t}=3$, I can have $y_{1,1}=y_{1,2}=y_{1,3}=y_{1,4}=1, y_{2,5}=y_{2,6}=y_{2,7}=1, y_{1,8}=y_{1,9}=y_{1,10}=1, \dots$, but I can't have $y_{3,1}=y_{3,2}=1, y_{2,3}=y_{2,4}=y_{2,5}=1, \dots$ because configuration 3 was kept only in two consecutive time intervals ($\bar{t}=3$).

Comment: To enforce $y_{1,1}=1 \implies y_{1,2}=y_{1,3}=1$, you need only impose $y_{1,1}\le y_{1,2}$ and $y_{1,1}\le y_{1,3}$.

Comment: I included another formulation that does not use additional variables, and all coefficients are $1$ or $-1$.